# Problema al ordenar por titulo

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una lista de videos que quiero ordenar por numero de capitulos he usado el

```
orderBy('title', 'ASC')
```

Pero esto solo hace que se ordenen

```
Capitulo 1
Capitulo 10
Capitulo 11
```

¿A qué se debe esto?, ¿debería convertir ese campo en otro tipo de dato?

Comment: Eso es porque tu campo contiene un `string` por lo que se va a ordenar alfabéticamente. Los números de tu `string` no van a ser interpretados como tal, por lo que 11 no es mayor que 2 ni siquiera 111 sería mayor que dos. Para entenderlo piensa en como ordena el diccionario (*a* sale antes que *e* y *aa* también saldría  antes que *e*)

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el ordenamiento es el indicado, el problema es que lo esta haciendo por el texto que aparece al inicio de la cadena.

Si lo que necesitas es un ordenamiento por el número de capítulos, en este caso te conviene mas agregar una nueva columna que maneje de forma exclusiva en forma numérica dicho dato; de manera que el ordenamiento si sea sobre una base contabilizable

Lo podemos hacer con:

```
ALTER TABLE TuTabla ADD COLUMN TotalCapitulos INT NOT NULL;
```

- Donde le indicamos que agregue una nueva columna de tipo entero a la tabla donde tienes almacenada la información de los videos
- Le indicamos que sea no nula para que de esa forma dicho valor nunca quede vacío

> Nota: siempre realiza primero un respaldo antes de proceder con la propuesta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías realizar el

```
ORDER BY
```

en 2 columnas.

```
ORDER BY capitulo ASC, título ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes porque estas utilizando la clausula `ORDER BY` con una columna que es texto. Si tienes una columna de tipo numérico donde tengas el numero de capitulo, debes realizar el `ORDER BY` con esa columna.

Si por algún motivo no puedes cambiar el tipo de datos, puedes utilizar la clausula `ORDER BY` de la siguiente forma:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(REPLACE(title,'Capitulo ',''), SIGNED)
```